# Yii2 composer upgrade not adding/updating files in project root?

Tags: php, yii2, upgrade, yii2-basic-app

I had an old Yii2 project that was built 2+ years ago on version 2.0.12, then left idle since around this time. Today I wanted to re-awaken this project and update it to the latest version
of Yii2 and all dependencies.

[Reading the Upgrade notes here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/UPGRADE.md) I saw that the following command will get me to the latest stable version:

> `composer require "yiisoft/yii2:~2.0.38" --update-with-dependencies`

After this command succeeded I confirmed by running `./yii` command in the project root that I am now on 2.0.38, however there are a few things missing. The main `README.md` remains the same as in version 2.0.12 and there are some files present in a clean build of 2.0.38 that remain missing from the root, e.g. `Vagrantfile` and `docker-compose.yml`.

Is there an undocumented step I am missing here to do this cleanly? Surely it's not down to manual intervention to go find/add these missing elements to *fully* upgrade?

Comment: Composer cannot manage files in your project. It only manages packages installed in vendor folder. Even if  you've created your project by running `composer create-project some/package` that only means that your project is created as copy of that package's current state. It won't be updated by composer afterwards even if the `some/package` changes.

Comment: @MichalHynčica true... so do you know if there is any mechanism that Yii has or intends for this "clean-up" after a composer upgrade? Or is manual the only way? Seems that some integrity can be lost with each upgrade

Comment: Manual is the only way but you don't really need to do that. The framework itself is in `yiisoft/yii2` and other packages that are updated by composer so your Yii is already updated. If you really need those files then you can simply bring them in. It's basically expected that you will customize these to match your needs or remove them if you are not going to use them.